# Resolve require Calls for browser output in Babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I want to transform ES6 to ES5 for browser usage (IE). Since I need some polyfills, `"useBuiltIns": "usage"` was set.

```
{
  "sourceType": "script",
  "ignore": ["gulpfile.js"],
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", 
      { "useBuiltIns": "usage" }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But the output file contains `require` statements at the beginning:

```
require("core-js/modules/es7.promise.finally");
require("core-js/modules/es6.function.name");
require("core-js/modules/es6.weak-map");
// ...
```

Why doesn't embed Babel 7 those files? As I understood [the documentation of sourceType](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype), we have `script` for browser usage, so that I get simply a single bundled file without any modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using browserify with Babbel plugin in my gulp task:

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
  babel = require("gulp-babel"),
  browserify = require("browserify"),
  fs = require("fs");

gulp.task("js", () => {
  let outputFolder = 'dist'
  let targetFile = "customization.js"
  const js = "src/js"
  let jsSources = [`${js}/polyfills.js`, `${js}/custom.js`]

  return browserify(jsSources)
    .transform("babelify")
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${outputFolder}/js/${targetFile}`))
})
```

This will create a single bundle without any module loaders.

Answer (score 1):

Babel isn't a bundler, it's just a transpiler for modern ES.

You'll need a bundler like Webpack or Parcel to convert `require()` function calls and/or `import` statements.